# Why is the limit of $\int {\frac{1}{z-z_0-x} - \frac{1}{z-z_0+x}}dz$ on a vertical segment as $x$ approaches $0$ not $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, complex-integration

A solution to the problem below is given by parametrization, converting the integral from $dz$ to $dt$. The result would be $ -2\pi i$, which would be correct.

My problem is why is it not $0$, which seems to be the case if I use a branch of the complex logarithm as an antiderivative. The problem and this attempt at a solution is below.

Fix a complex number $z_0 $ and a positive real number $c$.

Let $\sigma(t) :=z_0 + itc$ with $-1 \leq t \leq 1$.

Find $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \int_\sigma {\frac{1}{z-z_0-x} - \frac{1}{z-z_0+x}} dz$$

Attempt:

Let us take the principal branch of the complex logarithm, Log to get:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}[(Log(z-z_0-x)-Log(z-z_0+x))|_{z_0-ic}^{z_0+ic}]$$
Which is just the limit as $x$ approaches 0 of $$Log(ic - x) - Log (ic+x) -Log(-ic - x) + Log (-ic+x)$$ which is just $0$.

Comment: The problem is the use of the $Log$ since for example if the limit goes through $x>0$, you get a function that is real negative for $t=0$ so the principal branch of the logarithm is not usable the way done - in other words, $Log(itc-x)$ doesn't make sense with that branch for $t=0$; correcting that gives you precisely a $2\pi i$ jump btw

Comment: Thank you! I suspected that it was due to some property of the branches of the logarithm since $0$ and $-2\pi i$ differed by a multiple of $2\pi i$. I failed to consider the discontinuity of $Log$ on the negative reals which would have given a $2 \pi i$ jump.

Comment: Yes, and since the path is oriented upwards, the result is precisely $-2\pi i$ since splitting the first integral at zero to take into consideration the jump, you add the argument under the negative line and subtract the one above and with that the computation above becomes correct

Comment: Much appreciated! I suppose the problem of the solution above is that the discontinuity prevents Log from actually being a primitive for the function so that evaluating the integral on the path by subtracting its values on the endpoints would fail. The integral would have to be split as you stated. Things are clear now.

Comment: Yes exactly - using path additivity of the integral the split is legitimate and then $Log$ is indeed a primitive on both subpaths as it is now continuous on the subpaths (by taking the appropriate limit value at $t$ =$0$ on each)